# What is meant by finite harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, harmonic-oscillator

What does it mean to take finite harmonic oscillator,
In research article "http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/17/11/113015 ",

> we were finding effective number of cobosons in ground state $\langle N_0\rangle $ of multilevel system (harmonic trap) .There  they used approximation that $\langle N_0 \rangle = \langle N_0 \rangle _{f} - (T/T_0)^3 N S $.Where $\langle N_0 \rangle_f $ is number of cobosons in ground state for finite harmonic oscillator.

I  donnot understand how did they approximate it.

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kurt_Wolf2/publication/296616388_Finite_models_of_the_oscillator/links/0a85e53a081bc69845000000/Finite-models-of-the-oscillator.pdf or  https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/44365948/Finite_two-dimensional_oscillator_I._The20160403-27456-17b61wk.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1539255319&Signature=dTZmUEDqZBjvnZQ8ETnKF2vFqog%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DFinite_two-dimensional_oscillator_I._The.pdf? Basically the number of states is finite rather than infinite.

Comment: The system referred to by ZeroTheHero is often also called the *truncated* harmonic oscillator.