# Partition function and probability in finite harmonic trap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information

Let suppose we have $N$ number of cobosons in 3D harmonic trap. The effective number of cobosons in some state m is $\langle n_m\rangle$ that can be written as $\langle\hat{n}_m\rangle= \mathrm{Tr} [\hat{n_m}\rho ]$ where $\hat{n}_m$ is  number operator of cobosons while $\rho$ is density operator.If we assume our system in grand canonical ensemble , we can write effective number of cobosons as

$$\langle \hat{n}_m\rangle = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-(E_m -\mu)n/kT}/Z_m \cdot\rho$$
where $Z_m =1/(1- e^{-(E_m -\mu)/kT} )$.

Now for effective number of cobosons at ground state (energy at ground state is zero)
We can write 
$$\langle \hat{n}_o\rangle= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{(\mu)n/kT}/Z_0\cdot \rho$$
where $Z_0 =1/(1- e^{\mu/kT} )$.

Later for finite harmonic trap they wrote effective number of cobosons in ground state in the form 
We can write 
$$\langle \hat{n}_o\rangle= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n/N}/Z_0\cdot \rho$$
where $Z_0 = 1/(1- e^{-1)/N} )$.
How they wrote probability for finite harmonic trap?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433841/2451